# Amazon Web Services DynamoDB Inconstant in Updating Items

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using [Dynamoose](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose) to handle DynamoDB in my Node.js application. I have the function below that takes in a user id and adds the value to the value 'mynumber' and saves the new record.

```
function updateData(userid, value) {
    User.get(userid, function(err, user) {
        user.mynumber = user.mynumber + value;
        user.save(function(err) {});
    });
};
```

My issue is that just under half the time maybe this completely fails. When logging into the AWS DynamoDB console the record isn't updated after running this. I have tried running `console.log` before saving the record and it is accurate. But for some reason doesn't seem to be updating to the DB.

Any ideas for why updating this record would be so inconstant and work perfectly about half the time and the other half no changes are made?

Let me know if you need any more information or have any questions. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried logging the error from `save`?

Comment: @PatrickGoley Yes, it always returns `null`

Comment: Also important, `save` is asynchronous as it accepts a callback, but your `updateData` function doesn't. Are you checking immediately after calling `updateData`? Because it may take some time to complete.

Comment: @PatrickGoley Why would it matter if it is asynchronous? The DB should be updating either way. I'm not relying on that data to update right away. Even minutes after the AWS web console doesn't update. It's just strange. First time didn't update. Tried again and it worked. So it's just like hit or miss.

Comment: Ok, I was just making sure that you weren't attempting to log the updated record in a synchronous manner when it hadn't actually been updated yet.

Comment: @PatrickGoley Yeah. Currently just trying to view it in the AWS console.

Comment: @CharlieFish, can you try querying the data from code with "consistentRead" option as true, this option will make sure you get updated record

Comment: @HarshalBulsara Anyway to do that in the AWS console?

Comment: nope, I don't think so, have to do from code

Comment: @HarshalBulsara Seems strange that the AWS console won't update tho. That seems to me like it should be up to date

Comment: Yes it should update but i guess it might take some time, and if you think as application perspective then actually through code is more important, did you had a chance to check from code?

Comment: @HarshalBulsara Ok well it's been about what 3 hours or so and AWS console still hasn't updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118176/discussion-between-harshal-bulsara-and-charlie-fish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Just for future reference and in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

Basically I needed to create a callback that gets called after it actually saves. Looks like I was saving an element to the DB before the original was finished saving. So in some cases the save command above would finish before calling the next save but in other cases it would finish after and get re saved with the old value.

So running the code that runs after the save function above in a callback after that save gets completed seems to fix the issue.